# What are some major non-English technical works about bikes?

Tags: reference, bike-culture, resource, book

Of historical and present major technical works about bicycles, material that is intended to be higher level than everday DIY repair books sold to consumers, we have a number that are originally written in English. These could include:

- *Bicycles & Tricycles: A Classic Treatise on Their Design and Construction* by Sharp
- *Barnett's Manual*
- *Sutherland's Handbook*
- *The Bicycle Wheel* by Brandt
- *Bicycling Science* by Wilson
- *Bicyle Repairing* by Burr (a shop manual from 1896)

What are some similar works that were not originally written in English?

The above titles, while generally written with the goal of technical universiality, all find ways of slanting their content toward the predominant bike types found in North America and Europe, as well as the culture and the economics. What are some comparable works written by people with more career-spanning experience with, for example, Dutch bikes, Japanese market bikes, African CKD bikes, etc?

Note: This is not a request seeking recommendations, it is a question about what such works exist. Posting guidelines against seeking learning materials due to risk of obsolescence should not apply.

Comment: I support your assertion that obsolescence concerns shouldn’t apply here. The works you’ve listed are probably going to be relevant/useful so long as bicycles have two wheels—asking about their non-English counterparts seems perfectly valid. And either way, knowing about these works would have historical significance.